# How to use CNTK ProgressWriter class?

Tags: c#, .net, cntk

There is some docs about how to use TensorBoardProgressWriter class (Python) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Using-TensorBoard-for-Visualization

But how to use similar visualization/debug tools for .NET? I found class ProgressWriter in CNTK namespace, but how to use this?

Comment: I only use the python api. but i would imagine its the same?

Comment: I think too, but e.g. how to create output file?

Comment: In python i pass the progress writer class to the trainer class obj. Once training start the file will automatically get created. File path is defined when i initialise the progress writer, i think its log_to_dir argument in python.

Comment: Tried, no files appear. There is no input param like file_name or path in ProgressWriter

Comment: If thats the case, then i have no idea, sorry!

Comment: ProgressWriter is not completely implemented for C#, probably will be available in some future version. Meanwhile, it is possible to connect to internal pipeline using native unmanaged progress writer implementation, and calling it with pinvoke. I have a sample project which does that - https://github.com/ascvorcov/TensorBoardFileWriter